# Have to reboot with the headphone jack on to make it work ASUS GL504GW

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, drivers, headphone-jack

The problem is very simple.

After I boot my computer, if I plug my headphones, it works as if I did nothing (sound still goes through the internal speakers).

If I reboot with the headphones plugged in, then the sound is correctly directed to my headphones.

I would like it if the headphones could be detected automatically when plugged-in.

My computer is a laptop ASUS GL504GW with Nvidia High Definition Audio and Realtek Audio drivers (all got from ASUS or Windows Update). Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Do you have an audio driver application in the system tray? I think that this is normally a setting in there.

Comment: I don't have any icon in the system tray for audio. Which is the software I am missing?